# Left-Mouse Button Not Working

Tags: laptop, mouse, touchpad

For whatever reason my left-mouse button had stopped working. It's not stuck down as I can hear it clicking and my right button works, touchpad words ( this is a **laptop** ). What are some things I can do to figure out the problem / issue?

Comment: Try another mouse.

Comment: The 'fix' is strip it & clean or replace the micro-switch.

Answer (score 0):

Install XMBC and bind the middle mouse button to single click.
http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as in my question this is a Laptop, not a USB mouse.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee do your laptop mouse have any softwares installed? you can find them is control panel => hardware => mouse

Comment: Probably the drivers that came with the laptop.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Ok so now go to that program and set a gesture. laptop tochpads support gestures which means you can for example set single click for the corner of touchpad (when you tap there it is considered as a single click)

Comment: This sounds like a workaround than a fix.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee there is no fix. if you dont wanna do this, then you have to buy another mouse. sorry for that.

Comment: Installing media center software to fix a mouse problem? I don't get it.

Comment: @rrirower it is more than a media center app actually :D